# Python command Pandas Series data compare

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can you please help me with this command? I am trying to compare Col1 with Col2

I want to catch the value of the **number of FALSE**.

```
Data Frame: df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2], [3, 6], [3,3], [8,3]], columns = ["col1", "col2"])
```

```
MatchedData = df["Col1"].isin(df["Col2"]).value_counts()

OUTPUT:
True     4
```

In some cases columns are not mathing and they give false values.

How to write command to get number of false values in it.
I tried len(MatchedData["False"]) but it said **KEYWRRROR** while executing.

Comment: Please also show your dataframes so we can see what they look like.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2], [3, 6], [3,3], [8,3]], columns = ["col1", "col2"])

Comment: Question is still not clear, can you please use more detailing and markdown?

Comment: HI Chirag and Sandertjuhht, I completely changed my question in easy format and I hope it is clear now. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Your code does not run as-is because the column names are wrong (capital c). If I fix that, I can run the code and it doesn't produce the output you've shown (I get True 3, False 1), so please make sure to post the code that you run, and its output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for replying.

Here is the solution it worked for me. I am able to count number of False values.
Might be helpful for someone.

```
Counter = 0
for index, value in MatchedData.items():
   if(index == False):
      Counter  = Counter  + 1
```